# How to upload file from fragment webview in android?

Tags: file, webview, upload

I have used tabhost of two fragments. One fragment is for list and other is for webview. From that fragment I have to upload file from gallery. Following is my fragment for webview.

```
public class AppleFragment extends Fragment{

private static final String TAG = "SocialActivityFragment";
//protected static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 0;
WebView browser;
static String cookieString;
ProgressBar Pbar;
HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
 private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;  
 final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent) {  
  if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
  {  
   if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null  
                    : intent.getData();  
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
            mUploadMessage = null;  
  }
  }  
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.social_activities_layout, apple_versions);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.social_layout, null);
    Pbar = (ProgressBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.pB1);
    String strResponse = util.makeWebCall("http://google.com");

    DefaultHttpClient mClient = util.getClient();


    Cookie sessionInfo;
    List<Cookie> cookies = mClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (! cookies.isEmpty()){
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

        for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
                sessionInfo = cookie;
                cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + Sessions.getPhpSessid(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) + "; domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
                cookieManager.setCookie("http://youornot.com/social/", cookieString);
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cookieString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}

AlertDialogManager alert=new AlertDialogManager();
ConnectionDetector cd=new ConnectionDetector(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
if(!cd.isConnectedToInternet())
{
    alert.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Error..!", "You have not Connected to Internet", true);
}

browser=(WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webBrowser);
  // WebView browser = new WebView(SocialActivity.this);

WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();

browser.setScrollBarStyle(browser.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS);

WebViewClient wvClient = new WebViewClient();
browser.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

         mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
         i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
         i.setType("*/*");  
         getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

        }

     // For Android 3.0+
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
        FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

     //For Android 4.1
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
            i.setType("*/*");  
            getActivity().startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ),FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

        }

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
       {
       if(progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
           Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
           //txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
       Pbar.setProgress(progress);
       if(progress == 100) {
           Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
          // txtview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
    }
});

headerMap.put("Cookie", cookieString);
browser.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //The key is this line. 
                v.requestFocusFromTouch();  
                break;
        }               
        return false;
    }
});
browser.loadUrl("http://google.com", headerMap);


    return layout;//super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.web_menu, menu);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // handle item selection
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.refresh:
          browser.reload();
         // browser.loadUrl("http://google.com", headerMap);
         return true;
      default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}   
}
```

Whenever I am uploading file then webview is not responding at all.When i will close the application then also webview not responding. So how I can upload file in webview that is in the tabhost fragment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public class AppleFragment extends Fragment{

```
  WebView webView;

  //make HTML upload button work in Webview   
  private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
  private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

  @Override  
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {  
       if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
        {  
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
                     Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != getActivity().RESULT_OK ? null  
                             : intent.getData();  
                     mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
                     mUploadMessage = null;  
        }
   }  

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_web, container, false);

        // Web View
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

             //The undocumented magic method override  
             //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here  
             // For Android 3.0+
             public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  

                 mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
                 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
                 i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
                 i.setType("image/*");  
                 getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

                }

             // For Android 3.0+
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("*/*");
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                }

             //For Android 4.1
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
                    i.setType("image/*");  
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

                }
            });

        webView.loadUrl(yourUrl);

        return view;
  }
```

}

Comment: This code is run perfect for choosing the file file But. nothing will be uploaded in webview....It will show no file is for uploading....please select file to upload.... Please tell me how i can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

public class FragmentWeb extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

```
      if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
         {  

                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }

               Uri result=null;

               try{
                    if (resultCode != getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData(); 
                    } 
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
         }
   }
```

.
.
.
.
.
}

and YOU ALSO NEED TO PUT THE BELOW CODE AT MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

.
.
.
.
}

Comment: Thanks for this answer and one more thing is that MainActivity in androidManifest does not set launch mode "singleInstance".

Comment: It's default activity for fragment.